# Can I assign a specific IP address to any specific device under windows 11 pc's hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking

Can I assign a specific IP address to any specific device connected to my pc's hotspot?? It seems like whenever i restart my PC or the hotspot, it'll reassign random ip addresses to all of my devices. Is there any fix to that?

Comment: Generally you give same IP's via reservations in a router, without know your hotspots model I'm not sure it can do that. You could manually set static IP addresses on each device

Answer (score 0):

Hotspots are ad hoc devices.

What you need for your devices to have the same IP address, you need a router and a LAN.  Then you can set up as desired.

With a Hotspot, you cannot practically have static IP or unchanging IP addresses.

I use a LAN most of the time and hotspots occasionally. The Hotspot does not always have the same addressing which is the problem. Static IPs might work for a bit, but not all the time.

Comment: I know that, and thanks for your comment. But the router is a bit far from my actual using location, for example, my router is in hall room but my devices are in my living room. I use ethernet on my pc, so i use my router's wifi all my devices but some of my devices are too weak to get the signal from the router of that FAR position, so i need to use my desktop as a hotspot provider for those device. But i also need those device's ip address so i need to check for the ip addresses whenever i restart the pc or hotspot. I hope u understand the issue

Comment: You could possibly use a Wireless Router to make things easier for you

Comment: A decent router will allow you to do IP Reservation and solve many if not all your issue